# Set background colour for div with auto-scroll

Tags: html, css

I have used two div tags in my blog to wrap programming codes. The first one is used to set outline box with fixed width with the following CSS class:

```
.outlinebox {
  width: 435px;
  border-width: 1px;        /* sets border width on all sides */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  padding: 5px
}
```

The second div is used as inner box to set nowrap for codes with the class:

```
.nowrappercodesinner {
 width: auto;
 padding: 5px; 
 overflow: auto;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

I use those div tags for my codes in my blog. They work fine until I tried to add third div as inner area with a specific background colour. For example:

```
<div class="outlinebox">
  <div class="nowrappercodesinner">
     <div class style=""background-color:#cccccc;">
         ...
     </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that the background colour does not extend to the right when I move the horizontal scroll bar to the right. I am not sure if there is any way that the inner background colour will fill no matter where the scroll bar is moved.

Here I have one example in my recent blog: [Zip Files with PowerShell Script](http://davidchuprogramming.blogspot.com/2009/12/zip-files-with-powershell-script.html). You can see the problem in the third code block.

Comment: With Tom's help. I get it working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overflow: auto;

in the innermost div might help. At least it had the desired effect when I added the property in Firebug. I find it strange, still, because I thought `auto` is supposed to be the default setting.

EDIT: Default value for `overflow` seems to be `visible`.

Comment: Yes. The second div has this setting. It only works for that box and I have to make it consistent in the inner div as well. Great! Thank you Tom.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why do you need the third div? Couldn't you just put the background color on the second div?  I tried this on your blog in webkit's inspector and it displayed just fine.

```
<div class="outlinebox">
  <div class="nowrappercodesinner" style="background-color:#cccccc;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That could probably be accomplished with using different classes for the different codes, I would imagine. I just hate putting all those extra divs in my markup if I can avoid it.

Comment: I agree. However, this provides my a simple and flexible option to set background colour. I use VIM's syntax highlight colour templates. Now I have about 10 favourite ones. I may change in the future. In this sense, I would not need to maintain a group of classes.